# Macbook Air making rattling noise possibly because of fans

Tags: fan, macbook-air

In my somewhat more recent model Macbook Air, OS X Yosemite, I heard a loud rattling sound in the upper left corner of the keyboard. I pressed down on the upper left corner, near the esc key. That appears to be where the sound was coming from. Is there software to fix this or is this a hardware issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep that's the fan. No software could fix this.

You could try using compressed air to blow dust out the fan unit.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and just fixed it -- Give a soft knock on the underside of your laptop, under where the clicking is. (for me, a MacBook Air 11", it was under the ESC key). Just a good rap with your knuckles. When I did this, the fan immediately kicked in and engaged, and the clicking stopped.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I also tried punching it forcefully (not breaking it of course) but it didn't work. thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. When I knocked the underside of the macbook with my knuckles, underneath the escape key, the fan engaged and the rattling stopped.